# SSIS ERROR: cannot open the data file from path

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have 2 virtual machines VM1 and VM2. VM1 has a .csv file and VM2 is where the SQL instance exists. I created an SSIS package in Visual Studio on my personal machine. This package reads the data from the csv file on VM1 and simply dumps the data into a SQL table on an instance on VM2. The table has the same structure as the file. No data manipulation is going on here.

The package runs as it should in Visual studio on my machine so I deployed the package to the SQL Instance on VM2. Once the package is deployed, when I try to execute the package from the Integration Services catalog by connecting to the SQL instance thru SSMS on my machine, the package fails. Error message is in the title. However, when I RDP into VM2(as myself), and try to connect to the SQL instance thru SSMS, the package runs successfully.

I'm totally confused why that would be the case. Please advice.

Comment: Have you appropriately configured your system to use kerboros and avoid the "double hop" issue?

Comment: Yes, the service account that does the startup for both instances has kerberos enabled.

Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only) is checked.

Is it okay for both instances to have the same service account? Could that be what's causing the issue? I hope not.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is hop 1 and hop 2 with respect to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Control the security setting of your file to become sure appropriate user has access to the file. At first step add everyone user to access your file if it was solved change it to the user your SSIS runs under it. It can be your SQL Server integration service accounts has been used in services settings.